# Convert ZPL language to IPL Language

Tags: zpl, ipl

I have a Zebra printer and an Intermec printer (PD41). The code is in ZPL language, so my Zebra printer is working, but my Intermec printer doesn't. I need to write this code in IPL language so my Intermec understands the command. 
I can't update to ZSIM because my printer does not have enough memory to install the update that enables this function. So, I'll need to translate the code to IPL. This is my code:

```
Layout = "^XA^LL540^FO40,40^GB770,550,2^FS^FO30,60^XGR:Figure3.GRF,1,1^FS^FO390,50^GB410," & _ "170,2^FS^FO400,60^A0N,030,025^FDCAST NUMBER:^FS^FO400,100^A0N,115,90^FD" & _ strNumFusao & "^FS^FO50,230^GB205,140,2^FS^FO60,240^A0N,030,025^FDCAST MACHINE:^FS^FO110," & _ "275^A0N,110,85^FD" & strNumLing & "^FS^FO265,230^GB200,140,2^FS^FO275,240 ^A0N," & _ "030,025^FDBUNDLE: ^FS^FO320,275^A0N,110,85^FD" & strNumPilha & "^FS^FO475," & _ "230^GB325,140,2^FS^FO485,240^A0N,030,025^FDNET WEIGHT:^FS^FO545,275^A0N,110,85^FD" & _ strPesoLiquido & "^FS^FO80,390^A0N,30,40^FD" & strTexto1 & "^FS^FO80,430^A0N,30,40^FD" & _ strTexto2 & "^FS^FO180,470^BY2,3^B3N,N,80,Y,N^FD" & strCodBarra & "^XZ"
```

I'd like to convert and organize this code to IPL. There some IPL codes that I've identified:

```
^XA^ ^FS^ ^XGR^ ^FO x,y ^FD code ^GB x,y,z ^XZ
```

Does Anyone support me pls!!

Comment: Would probably be cheaper to buy a new additional zebra printer, or Intermec printer that has ZSIM, than to code something to convert it. Also easier to support 1 program than 2. And easier to support 1 model printer than 2.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, all PD41 versions have ZSIM installed.

If you still want to translate ZPL commands to intermec language, I will try DP (Direct Protocol) first, not IPL.

You should take the ZPL manual and understand each command, 
and then find the corresponding command in DP.

[Programming Guide for ZPL II, ZBI 2](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/en-us/software/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf)
[Intermec Direct Protocol 8.60 Programmer's Reference Manual](http://epsfiles.intermec.com/eps_files/eps_man/1-960597-06%20PRM%20DP%208.60.pdf)

Each ZPL command is identified by a starting escape character, the default is the caret `"^"`.

A ZPL layout have a fixed structure, starts with `^XA` and ends with `^XZ`.

Try to look at your ZPL layout in this way and you will find it easier than you expect:

```
^XA
^LL540
^FO40,40
^GB770,550,2
^FS
^FO30,60
^XGR:Figure3.GRF,1,1
^FS
^FO390,50
^GB410,170,2
^FS
^FO400,60
^A0N,030,025
^FDCAST NUMBER:
^FS
^FO400,100
^A0N,115,90
^FD strNumFusao 
^FS
^FO50,230
^GB205,140,2
^FS
^FO60,240
^A0N,030,025
^FDCAST MACHINE:
^FS
^FO110,275
^A0N,110,85
^FD strNumLing 
^FS
^FO265,230
^GB200,140,2
^FS
^FO275,240 
^A0N,030,025
^FDBUNDLE: 
^FS
^FO320,275
^A0N,110,85
^FD strNumPilha 
^FS
^FO475,230
^GB325,140,2
^FS
^FO485,240
^A0N,030,025
^FDNET WEIGHT:
^FS
^FO545,275
^A0N,110,85
^FD strPesoLiquido 
^FS
^FO80,390
^A0N,30,40
^FD strTexto1 
^FS
^FO80,430
^A0N,30,40
^FD strTexto2 
^FS
^FO180,470
^BY2,3
^B3N,N,80,Y,N
^FD strCodBarra 
^XZ
```

Comment: Upvote for zsim, you probably won't have to change your code at all.